# WCF Multiple requests from same client

Tags: wcf

i am building a WCF Service and i need clients to be able to acquire multiple results in the same time.
For example 5 callings of void UploadPhoto(byte[] photo);
and 1 string GetInfo()

If I understand it correctly, than whenever I do a request for a service, I need to get a response for the first one before the second gets proceeded. Is that correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not quite correct.

If you call a WCF (or other web service) syncronosly then you have to wait for the response before doing anything else.

However, you can call a wcf service asyncronosly, in which case you do not have to wait for the result. You create a handler that handles the result when it comes back, but the main program continues.

Have a look at Ladislav's answer to this question: [Difference between WCF sync and async call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793068/difference-between-wcf-sync-and-async-call)

Answer (score 2):

You can make multiple calls if you increase the `System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` the default is 2.

You need to set the WCF Service as [Per-Call Service](http://wcftutorial.net/Per-Call-Service.aspx) to process concurrent requests.